# How to unit test and mock parentElement of ElementRef - Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-unit-test, elementref

I have a scroll-animation component which i can add to some other components in order to display a scroll animation. The scroll animation will be shown when the parent component has scroll-bar.

```
export class ScrollIndicatorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
}

...

componentHasScrollbar(): boolean {
    const parentElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement;
    return parentElement.offsetHeight < parentElement.scrollHeight;
}
```

How can i mock the this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement and its offsetHeight and scrollHeight values, so the method componentHasScrollbar() will return true in my unit test?

Answer (score 2):

I would create a function which returns this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement, and then in the unit test you can spy on that function and mock the result

```
private getParentElement(): HTMLElement {
  return this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement;
}

componentHasScrollbar(): boolean {
  const parentElement = this.getParentElement();
  return parentElement.offsetHeight < parentElement.scrollHeight;
}
```

Then in tests:

```
spyOn(component, 'getParentElement').and.returnValue({
   scrollHeight: 10,
   offsetHeight: 1000
})
```

Your tests should trust that ElementRef itself is sufficiently tested.

Some may argue that this approach is changing the code to suit the tests, but I believe this approach is encouraging cleaner code.

Comment: Not quite the answer to the question, but nevertheless a nice solution. Thank you!